# loop questions Python

Tags: python, loops

I need to ask a user how many people are booking in , max 8 people then take that amount and ask for user 1 details, user 2 details etc.save details to be printed later.Not sure what to I'm very new to python.

```
manager_name = raw_input("please enter managers Name: ")
email_address = raw_input("please enter your Email Address: ")
phone_number = raw_input("please enter your Phone number: ")



print("-----------------------------------------------------")
print ("Our Stuido can Accommodate up to max 8 musicians")
print("-----------------------------------------------------")

amount_of_band_members = int(raw_input("please enter the amount of band members"))

values = []
for i in range(amount_of_band_members):
values.append(int(input('Please enter Muscians Names & Insterments: ')))
```

Comment: Indentation matters

Answer (score 0):

```
manager_name = raw_input("please enter managers Name: ")
email_address = raw_input("please enter your Email Address: ")
phone_number = raw_input("please enter your Phone number: ")


print("-----------------------------------------------------")
print ("Our Stuido can Accommodate up to max 8 musicians")
print("-----------------------------------------------------")

amount_of_band_members = int(raw_input("please enter the amount of band members"))

if amount_of_band_members >8:
    print ("Sorry we can only Accommodate maxuim 8 Musicians")
else :
    print raw_input("please enter musicians and insterments")


while amount_of_band_members <8:
    print raw_input("please enter next name")
    amount_of_band_members +=1
```